# How to know button name?

Tags: html, vba

How could I know the name of the button if the name="buttonname" tag is not present?
Here is the script of the button.

```
a class="button" onclick="callSubmit()" href="#"
```

I need to know the tag since in vba I would want to do something like this

```
ie.Document.all("Buttonname").Click
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have any idea how to click that element using vba?

Comment: IE's document.all uses the id attribute, so something like `<a id='Buttonname' class=...>`

Comment: You will need to use some other way of identifying the element - perhaps it's text or other property? Or you could use DOM and get the element from its `xpath`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the HTML element has no name attribute, is has simply no name. There is no hidden or default name you can query.

Give it a name or preferably an id. You can also query child elements for example or then n-th element, but there are excellent answers on that already on SO.

Comment: so there is no way to call the element then?

Comment: @user61835 why would you need to? As it is essentially an 'anonymous' caller, the equivalent would be to justy call its onClick

Comment: so there is another way in vba to click that button?

Comment: I am doing macros using VBA

Comment: Yes, inside Microsoft Excel

Comment: Then please show more surrounding VBA code do we get a clue. Still my answer stands. Can't you change the HTML?

Comment: Assuming OP is using VBA to scrape the web, the recommendation to "Change the HTML" doesn't really make sense. While OP could certainly clarify a bit, I don't think this is really an answer to the question: sure, element doesn't have a name, but there are other ways to *get* that element which you've mentioned but not demonstrated. Your answer as such seems more like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DavidZemens We can only answer the questions that are asked; not the ones OP meant to ask.